# Pass translate value in input compnent

Tags: angular, angular10

I use angular 10.
I have an accordion group and this accordion group has an `[heading]` for the title of the accordion

```
<accordion-group *ngFor="let notif of notifResponse.notifs.content" 
     [heading]="{{ notif.title | translate }}" [panelClass]="'border'">
   
 </accordion-group>
```

My code `[heading]="{{ notif.title | translate }}"` doesn't work. I have an error unexpeted token...and many errors in the logs.

How could I get the value of my variable, translate it and send it to the input ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all ``[heading]="{{ notif.title | translate }}"`` -> ``[heading]="notif.title | translate"``

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided by Ivan works. `[heading]="notif.title | translate"`. Thanks